# API Gateway to ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-alb

I have a question about #apigateway and thanks in advance for all your insights.

#aws #apigateway REST APIs seems like can integrate only with Network Load Balancer out of box using private link. But in my use case, I want to use Application Load Balancer, is the only way around it is to make it internet facing load balancer?

If yes, what do you all think about this solution architecture? End of the day I would want Application Load Balancer to be accessible only through API Gateway. What are the risk you see with this solution?

[image]

#awscloud #awscertified  #awscommunity #awssecurity #aws #cloudarchitecture

Comment: I don't understand, why your API Gateway is in a VPC? Is it supposed to be private API gateway?

Comment: It is to represent that API Gateway is in aws network, not the customer VPC. And the Gateway is regional

Comment: Why the authenitcatio is on ALB? Why not make it on the API? Woud;t it be easier to deny access right at the beginig, rather then after API and WAF?

Comment: Authentication on ALB is more to prevent direct hit to ALB and that the headers are passed through API Gateway.

Comment: I've got a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399975/how-to-integrate-api-gateway-with-internal-alb
Did you end up integrationg API Gateway with ALB?